# Method reference - Difference between "Reference to a static method" and "Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type"

Tags: java, lambda, method-reference

I've learned that there are 4 kinds of types in method reference. But I don't understand the difference between "***Reference to a static method***" and "***Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type***".

For example:

```
  List<String> weeks = new ArrayList<>();
  weeks.add("Monday");
  weeks.add("Tuesday");
  weeks.add("Wednesday");
  weeks.add("Thursday");
  weeks.add("Friday");
  weeks.add("Saturday");
  weeks.add("Sunday");
  weeks.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).forEach(System.out::println);
```

The method `toUpperCase` is **not** a `static` method... so why can one write in the way above, rather than needing to use it this way:

```
 weeks.stream().map(s -> s.toUpperCase()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

> The method `toUpperCase` is **not** a static method... so why can one write in the way above, rather than needing to use it this way:
>
> ```
> weeks.stream().map(s -> s.toUpperCase()).forEach(System.out::println);
> ```

Method references **are not limited** to `static` methods. Take a look at

```
.map(String::toUpperCase)
```

it is equivalent to

```
.map(s -> s.toUpperCase())
```

Java will just call the method you have referenced on the elements in the stream. In fact, this is the whole point of references.

The official [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) explains this in more detail.

---

### Insights, Examples

The method `Stream#map` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)) has the following signature:

```
<R> Stream<R> map​(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper)
```

So it expects some `Function`. In your case this is a `Function<String, String>` which takes a `String`, applies some method on it and then returns a `String`.

Now we take a look at `Function` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)). It has the following method:

> `R apply​(T t)`
>
> Applies this function to the given argument.

This is exactly what you are providing with your method reference. You provide a `Function<String, String>` that applies the given method reference on all objects. Your `apply` would look like:

```
String apply(String t) {
    return t.toUpperCase();
}
```

And the Lambda expression

```
.map(s -> s.toUpperCase())
```

generates the **exact same** `Function` with the same `apply` method.

So what you could do is

```
Function<String, String> toUpper1 = String::toUpperCase;
Function<String, String> toUpper2 = s -> s.toUpperCase();

System.out.println(toUpper1.apply("test"));
System.out.println(toUpper2.apply("test"));
```

And they will both output `"TEST"`, they behave the same.

More details on this can be found in the Java Language Specification [JLS§15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13). Especially take a look at the examples in the end of the chapter.

Another note, why does Java even know that `String::toUpperCase` should be interpreted as `Function<String, String>`? Well, in general it does not. That's why we always need to clearly specify the type:

```
// The left side of the statement makes it clear to the compiler
Function<String, String> toUpper1 = String::toUpperCase;

// The signature of the 'map' method makes it clear to the compiler
.map(String::toUpperCase)
```

Also note that we can only do such stuff with **functional interfaces**:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function<T, R> { ... }
```

---

### Note on `System.out::println`

For some reason you are not confused by

```
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This method **is not** `static` either.

The `out` is an ordinary object instance and the `println` is a non `static` method of the `PrintStream` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)) class. See [System#out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) for the objects documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Method reference quite intelligent feature in Java. So, when you use non-static method reference like `String:toUpperCase` Java automatically comes to know that it needs to call `toUpperCase` on the on the first parameter.Suppose there is two parameter a lambda expression expect then the method will `call` on the `first parameter` and the `second parameter` will pass as an `argument` of the method. Let' take an example.

```
List<String> empNames = Arrays.asList("Tom","Bob");
String s1 = empNames.stream().reduce("",String::concat); //line -1
String s2 = empNames.stream().reduce("",(a,b)->a.concat(b)); // line -2
System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
```

So, on above example on line -1, String#concat method will `call` on the first parameter (that is `a` line-2) and a second parameter (that `b` for line -2) will pass as the `argument`.

It is possible for the multiple arguments (more than 2) method also but you need to very careful about the which sequence of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to read the Oracle's article about method references: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

That is the form of a lambda expression:

```
s->s.toUpperCase()
```

And that is a method reference:

```
String::toUpperCase
```

Semantically, the method reference is the same as the lambda expression, it just has different syntax.