# Method reference for static and instance methods

Tags: java, method-reference

I am unable to grasp the concept of Method references in case of instance methods in Java

For example in the example below, the compiler is giving error in the list line.

I have seen the examples of String::toUpperCase.

I am confused over the point that
(1) String is a class and toUpperCase is instance method. Java allows String::toUpperCase
(2) Why it is not allowing in my case:- AppTest::makeUppercase

```
package mja;

import java.util.function.Function;
public class AppTest {

    public String makeUppercase(String source){
        return source.toUpperCase();
    }
    
    public void printFormattedString(String string, Function<String, String> formatter){
        System.out.println(formatter.apply(string));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppTest appTest = new AppTest();
        String source = "Hello World!";
        
        // Below statement compiled successfully
        appTest.printFormattedString(source, appTest::makeUppercase);

        // Getting error that non-static method can't be referenced from static context
        appTest.printFormattedString(source, AppTest::makeUppercase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the "String::toUpperCase" example? I think you'll see the context matters. One is probably in a streaming context where the type of the function is known.

Comment: Hi @matt , see this for example , compiler is not giving any error in this line.

IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).mapToObj(Integer::toString) .forEach(System.out::println);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why it is not allowing `AppTest::makeUppercase`?

The short answer is that `AppTest::makeUppercase` isn't valid *"reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type"*.
`AppTest::makeUppercase` must implement interface `Function<AppTest, String>` to be valid reference.

Details:

There are [4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html#static) kinds of method references in Java:

1. `ContainingClass::staticMethodName` - reference to a static method
2. `containingObject::instanceMethodName` - reference to an instance method of a particular object
3. `ContainingType::methodName` - reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type
4. `ClassName::new` - reference to a constructor

Every single kind of method reference requires corresponding `Function` interface implementation.
You use as a parameter the reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type.
This kind of method reference has no explicit parameter variable in a method reference and requires implementation of the interface `Function<ContainingType, String>`. In other words, the type of the left operand has to be `AppTest` to make `AppTest::makeUppercase` compilable. `String::toUpperCase` works properly because the type of parameter and type of the instance are the same - `String`.

```java
import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

class ReferenceSource {

    private String value;

    public ReferenceSource() {
    }

    public ReferenceSource(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String doInstanceMethodOfParticularObject(final String value) {
        return ReferenceSource.toUpperCase(value);
    }

    public static String doStaticMethod(final String value) {
        return ReferenceSource.toUpperCase(value);
    }

    public String doInstanceMethodOfArbitraryObjectOfParticularType() {
        return ReferenceSource.toUpperCase(this.value);
    }

    private static String toUpperCase(final String value) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(value).map(String::toUpperCase).orElse("");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        // #1 Ref. to a constructor
        final Supplier<ReferenceSource> refConstructor = ReferenceSource::new;
        final Function<String, ReferenceSource> refParameterizedConstructor = value -> new ReferenceSource(value);

        final ReferenceSource methodReferenceInstance = refConstructor.get();

        // #2 Ref. to an instance method of a particular object
        final UnaryOperator<String> refInstanceMethodOfParticularObject = methodReferenceInstance::doInstanceMethodOfParticularObject;

        // #3 Ref. to a static method
        final UnaryOperator<String> refStaticMethod = ReferenceSource::doStaticMethod;

        // #4 Ref. to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type
        final Function<ReferenceSource, String> refInstanceMethodOfArbitraryObjectOfParticularType = ReferenceSource::doInstanceMethodOfArbitraryObjectOfParticularType;

        Arrays.stream(new String[] { "a", "b", "c" }).map(refInstanceMethodOfParticularObject).forEach(out::print);
        Arrays.stream(new String[] { "d", "e", "f" }).map(refStaticMethod).forEach(out::print);
        Arrays.stream(new String[] { "g", "h", "i" }).map(refParameterizedConstructor).map(refInstanceMethodOfArbitraryObjectOfParticularType)
                .forEach(out::print);
    }
}
```

Additionally, you could take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49349261/method-reference-difference-to-lambda) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533345/what-does-an-arbitrary-object-of-a-particular-type-mean-in-java-8) thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
String::toUpperCase
```

is short version of

```
text -> {
    return text.toUpperCase();
}
```

is again short version of

```
new Functon<String, String> (String text) {
    Override
    public String apply(String text) {
        return text.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

so when you want AppTest::myMethod

you need

```
public class AppTest {

    public String myMethod(){
        return this.toString();
    }

    public void printFormattedString2(AppTest appTest, Function<AppTest, String> formatter){
        System.out.println(formatter.apply(appTest));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppTest appTest = new AppTest();

        appTest.printFormattedString2(appTest, AppTest::myMethod);
    }
}
```

because whole version looks so

```
appTest.printFormattedString2(appTest, new Function<AppTest, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(AppTest text) {
        return text.makeUppercase2();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @anatoli

I have added new method to AppTest class compiler is still giving me same error when I am calling appTest.testMethodRef(appTest, AppTest::getSelf);

public AppTest getSelf(AppTest appTest){
        return appTest;
    }

    public void testMethodRef(AppTest appTestObj, Function<AppTest, AppTest> formatter){
        System.out.println(formatter.apply(appTestObj));
    }

Comment: Hi @anatoli,

error went away now, but still didn't get the theory behind it. i.e. What concept differs both styles.

Does it simply mean that to call the second way your instance method should return the Same type it is implemented in ?

Comment: Hi @NiteeshBhargava, unfortunatelly i don't have a good example how to make it clearer, but no, you don't need to have same types. Also in the example `myMethod` returns a String and not `AppTest` class. [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html) you could read soe more.

Comment: I think a succinct way to denote the difference is that the container of a method reference (`container::reference`) can refer to either the type of an input, or the reference's location. So `MyClass::staticMethod` could satisify the functional interface requirements for _both_ `(MyClass instance) -> instance.staticMethod();` and `() -> MyClass.staticMethod();`, the former due to backward compat.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let us edit your class as below.

```
public class AppTest {
    private String name;
    public AppTest(String name){ this.name = name; }

    public String makeUppercase() { //I have removed the argument here!!
        return this.name.toUpperCase();
    }
    psvm main(){
        AppTest appTest = new AppTest("Hello");
        Stream.of(appTest).map(AppTest::makeUppercase).forEach(System.out::println); 
        //Here makeUppercase works of objects of type AppData similar to how String::toUpperCase works on object of type String!
    }
}
```

This is accepted. Why?

Here, `AppTest::makeUppercase` is an instance method that operates on `this` instance of `AppTest`.

Why was yours not working?

```
appTest.printFormattedString(source, AppTest::makeUppercase);
```

This was not working because you are required to pass an implementation of `Function`. And, makeUpperCase() `Function` was not accessible from a non-static context since the method `makeUpperCase()` works on objects of type `AppData`. So, you need `AppData` instance to call this method!

Maybe you should change your method to be static and use it like this,

```
appTest.printFormattedString("Hello", AppTest::makeUppercase);
```

Why is the following code working?

```
appTest.printFormattedString(source, appTest::makeUppercase);
```

Because, you created an instance of `AppTest` and accessing the `makeUppercase` method (which is the implementation) and passing it as an argument to `printFormattedString`.

You need objects of a particular type to access the non-static method. But, You do not need objects of a particular type to access the static method.

`String::toUpperCase` works on instances of `String`. But you cannot access this method without having a `String` object to work on. Refer my comment in the code block to understand this better.